# Query only non-null value and rename the fields?

Tags: csv, powershell, active-directory

Here's what I am trying to do:

1. Query a few properties in AD and list only the one which the `DisplayName` is not empty.
2. Save to the CSV with all the fields queried
3. Eliminate the first line of the CSV file, and then rename all the column name.

Here's what I currently have:

```
Get-AdUser -Filter * -Properties DisplayName, Memberof |
  select DisplayName, Memberof |
  Export-Csv ********
```

Here are the problems:

1. The `MemberOf` field display on the following but now the real group names:

   ```
   Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection
   ```
2. I can't seem to find the way to replace the column name into ones I want it to be called "Name", "group", etc.
3. The first line of the csv file contains the following:

   ```
   #TYPE Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser
   ```

Is there a quick fix for this by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the key concepts to learn here is [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx). This let's you modify data on the fly as you `Select` it, making it more useful to your overall goal within the script (whatever that may be).

So for your questions:

1. This is because `memberOf` isn't a simple string, it has it own .NET type of `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection`. To expand that value, use this calculated property in your `select` statement

   ```
   select displayName, @{name="MemberOf"; expression={$_.memberof -join ";"}}
   ```
2. Again, you can use a calculated property. Say you wanted to change "displayName" to "Display Name:. You'd use something like:

   ```
   select @{name="Display Name";expression={$_.displayName}}, @{name="MemberOf"; expression={$_.memberof -join ";"}}
   ```
3. When exporting a CSV to remove that `#TYPE` declaration at the beginning, add the `-NoTypeInformation` argument to your `Export-Csv` cmdlet. So:

   ```
   Export-csv -NoTypeInformation "myfile.csv"
   ```

Also, your filter on your initial `Get-AdUser` might need to be changed if you only want users that don't have an empty displayName. Something like:

```
Get-AdUser -Filter {DisplayName -ne ''} -Properties DisplayName, Memberof
```

Comment: Hello, everything you provided is spot on except for the last one....It gives me an error for Get-AdUser -Filter {$_.DisplayName -ne ''} . Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, think I used the `this` keyword when I didn't need to. I've edited my response, but try using `-Filter {DisplayName -ne ''}` instead (note I removed the `$_.`)

Comment: PS C:\Windows> Get-AdUser -Filter {DisplayName -ne ''} -Properties DisplayName,
Memberof
Get-AdUser : The search filter cannot be recognized
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AdUser -Filter {DisplayName -ne ''} -Properties DisplayName, Memberof
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The search filter cannot be recognized,Microsoft
   .ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Comment: I think it doesn't like the double single quotes, well this isn't as fast, but it should work. Sorry, can't test this, no longer have access to an AD environ, but I think it should work: `Get-AdUser -Filter * -Properties DisplayName, Memberof | Where{ -not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.DisplayName)) } | Select ...`

Comment: You could also try `Get-AdUser -Filter {DisplayName -like "*"}`

Answer (score 0):

Also discovered this QUEST AD toolkit. Download it from the dell website, and then just Add-PASSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement. This is way easier for us to query any AD related data.

Comment: Cool! To add a link in case anyone else is looking for this, this looks to be the location - http://software.dell.com/products/activeroles-server/powershell.aspx